# Complex differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, complex

I want to solve $dx/dt=\sqrt{(1-x^2)}$, where $x$ is complex. When I solve it by hand and analytically for some initial value and draw the imaginary part versus the real part, I obtain an ellipse, as expected. I tried to solve it with *Mathematica*, but I failed. Here is my code:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1 - x[t]^2)^0.5, x[0] == 1 + I}, x[t], {t, 0, 10},
      Method -> "ExplicitMidpoint",   "StartingStepSize" -> 1/10];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. s], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would appreciate if someone could help me to fix the problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I don't have this error message on _v8_.

Comment: @Öskå. Got message ">NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 0.9045874497947668`. >>
" from V9.0.1 running on OS X

Comment: @m_goldberg That's what I expected :) I guess it's relevant to have it as a comment or as a side note in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

`NDSolve` is having trouble dealing with `t` outside the interval `{-2.235, .9}`. Also, for the initial condition `x[0] == 1 + I`, it only gets the top half of the ellipse. A work-around is:

```
s1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1. - x[t]^2)^0.5, x[0] == 1 + I}, x, {t, -2.235, .9}];
s2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1. - x[t]^2)^0.5, x[0] == 1 - I}, x, {t, -2.235, .9}];
pp1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. s1], {t, -2.235, .9}];
pp2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. s2], {t, -2.235, .9}];
Show[pp1, pp2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Actually I want to use this code for more general equations such as dx/dt=sqrt(1 + (I x)^3), for example for x(0)=-2 - 3I. But it seems it does not work for this case. How can I generalize this code for this equation?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = Quiet@DSolve[{x'[t]==(1-x[t]^2)^(1/2),x[0]==1+I},x[t],t][[1]]
```

> {x[t] -> Sin[t + ArcSin[1 + I]]}

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]],Im[x[t]]}/.s],{t,0,2Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your attention. But I want to solve it numerically, I mean by NDSolve. Because I want to apply the method for equations which do not have analytic answer, like: dx/dt=sqrt(1+(I x)^3) .

Comment: I removed `Off[]` and replaced it by `Quiet`. After using `Off[]` one needs to turn `On[]` again the messages. `Quiet` has the same effect in that case.